# SwiftUI picker not updating value

Tags: swiftui

I have a picker for choosing categories. Each category has an id property that is a string. This does display the correct initial value. However, if I open the picker and choose a new value, `categoryId` is never updated.

```
@EnvironmentObject var data: TransactionData
@State var categoryId: String = ""

var body: some View {
    Form {
        Section {
            Picker(selection: $categoryId, label: Text("Category")) {
                ForEach(data.categories) { category in
                    Text(category.name).tag(category.id)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `tag` method is for a View, not for the value you want the Picker to be. See here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/picker/3303057-tag. Also try assigning an `id` in your `ForEach` to be the `category.id`.

Comment: I believe Text() is considered a view and this is how to docs say to do it. I also have categories setup with Identifiable so the ForEach thing is unnecessary. Also I want to point out that this displays the correct initial value.